# How to set Focus to the first row in a JTable which is inside a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I have a `JTable` inside a `JScrollPane`. I have put this inside a panel. As soon the panel loads I want the first row in the JTable to get the focus BUT by default the focus goes to the `JScrollPane` and on pressing tab the focus enters into table's first row.
I dont want to use `setRowSelectionInterval(0,0)` and `setColumnSelectionInterval(0,0)` as my requirement is different from that.

Comment: you want to edit first cell or just want it selected?

Comment: _as my requirement is different from that_ - then: what exactly _is_ your requirement?

Comment: I just want it to be selected, n especially the first cell of the first row must be focused. If i print the first focusable component, it prints JScrollPane, i want it to return first row in a Jtable.

Answer (score 18):

If you want to edit cell you can use,

```
jTable1.requestFocus();
jTable1.editCellAt(row,column);
```

Or else you want to just select the  row, you can use,

```
jTable1.requestFocus();
jTable1.changeSelection(row,column,false, false);
```

Answer (score 8):

- try with `myTable.changeSelection(row, column, false, false);`
- depends of [ListSelectionModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection)