# How can I "go to" a specific row in a JTable when user press a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton, actionlistener

Hi everybody I'am kind of a noob using java.swing and I would like to know if you could help me with the following issue:

- I have a JFrame containing several JPanels where each JPanel is an
  eyelash with their own JTable.
- In each JTable there are double type values referring to € amounts.
- In a static variable I keep the max value of all the eyelash.

So my point is that I want to use a JButton that takes me to the eyelash and the row where I have the max value.

**In example:** If max value is in eyelash 3, row 55 I want that when pressing the button the programs takes me to visualize this row.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Focus to the first row in a JTable which is inside a JScrollPane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365294/how-to-set-focus-to-the-first-row-in-a-jtable-which-is-inside-a-jscrollpane)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JTable Scrolling to a Specified Row Index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853020/jtable-scrolling-to-a-specified-row-index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example you want to select the row `x`

```
Rectangle rect = myTable.getCellRect(x, 0, true);
myTable.scrollRectToVisible(rect); // scroll to the row
myTable.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(x, x); // and select it (when required)
```